# React - Set state in child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to Reacts.  I read a lot post and I can not find a solution to my problem.

I have several components. One is Gallery on which ajax request is called to get values.Another component is InnerContent. Its a child component of Gallery.

My question is it correct to set state as props in child component, in my case (InnerContent)?

**This is my input data:**

```
[
      {
        "collection": 1,
        "article": 1,
        "name": "Gallery 2",
        "images": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "aaa",
            "src": "http://via.placeholder.com/200x200"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "bbb",
            "src": "http://via.placeholder.com/200x200"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

**Here is my code:**

```
    class InnerContent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      images: this.props.data.images,
    };
  }

 removeImage() {
   /*change state in this Component*/
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Gallery name: {this.props.data.name}</div>
        <GalleryImageContent>
          <SortableItem removeImage={this.removeImage} {...this.state} />
        </GalleryImageContent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Content(props) {
  let rows = [];

  props.data.forEach((data) => {
    rows.push(<InnerContent data={data}/>)
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {rows}
    </div>
  );
}

class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: Service.data
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={/*change state*/}>Add Gallery</button>
        <Content data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your question ? yes you can assign the props to the state of your child component

Comment: It would help if you created a simplified version of your issue instead of having us have to dig through your code. I assume you're trying to change the state in your parent component. If so, create a function that changes state, i.e, `updateField = (newVal) => this.setState({field: newVal});` and pass this function to your child component via props, then call it like this `this.props.updateField(val);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is okay to set state as props in child component.

You have to just take care of one more condition in your case. You're setting the state in a `constructor`, but when the component is rendered the second time and the `props` change, the state remains the same as the `constructor` is called only once.

Basically, you have to keep the component's `state` up to date with the props. You can use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` function to solve this.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    images: nextProps.data.images
  });
}
```

Let me know if it solves your problem.